# Learning Python

Tags: python

I am going to need to learn advanced Python and must be good at it in about a year, Are there any books, recommendations. I am already very familiar with PHP, MySQL, JS + HTML, and know a bit of java and C (arduino programming).

Thanks,
RayQuang

Comment: "must be good at it" to accomplish what kind of tasks?

Comment: This is for general programming, e.g. writing scripts to alert me when a server goes down, server management, network monitoring, possibly arduino control, web application back ends etc... Not to mention for my job as CTO at RayQuang Industries

Comment: Good youtube course that teaches python from scratch. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrEuolFXVqQA-1dxUwl-Wq-0Fnl5SyVKz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you sound like a competent programmer, the best place to start may be the official [Python 2.7 Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html). It's very thorough, certainly.

After that, I advise looking up through the [language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/index.html) and [standard library reference](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html) (the stdlib for Python is pretty massive) to get everything else.

Comment: Good youtube course that teaches python from scratch. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrEuolFXVqQA-1dxUwl-Wq-0Fnl5SyVKz

Answer (score 3):

It's not a book, but I found the [Google Python Class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/index.html) very useful. There's video, reading material, and practice questions that I found very useful.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of good resources, either at [the python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/), or here at previous similar questions.

Generally I would recommend starting with the [official python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). Alternatively, you might want to check [other tutorials](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers), aimed for people with previous programming experience.

Afterwards, you can try books, such as '[Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/)', but I always preferred sharpening my skills by trying a set of problems, such as [python challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/) and [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/).

I think that trying to solve such problems is a good advice for every programmer who's trying to learn a new language.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at Mark Lutz's book..

it's more than an introduction, but it's not very thorough

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565924642

once you finished that one, if you found it useful you might want to pass at:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596158118?green=18666053383&cmp=af-mybuy-9780596158118.IP

another interesting one is the Python Cookbook

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001674 (careful, it's 6 years old)

the official tutorials are very useful, too ;)

Comment: I'd hesitate to recommend the Python Cookbook as even the 2nd edition only covers Python 2.4. A lot has changed in the last six years.

Comment: uhm...maybe it can result useful, at the end..however edited, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are a lot of good books being recommended. Be aware that there are two main versions of Python in circulation. 3.0 is the new, and a lot of 2.7 programs won't work with 3.0. Some of the syntax has been tidied up - and one of the most common problems is "print" which now has a syntax more consistent with the rest of the language.

As with any language, the best way to learn it is to start using it. Choose a project which pulls to Python's strengths (eg. text processing and data structures) and your probable needs in 12 months time, and start coding!

Comment: Good youtube course that teaches python from scratch. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrEuolFXVqQA-1dxUwl-Wq-0Fnl5SyVKz

Answer (score 1):

I have good books, but I don't know exactly what do you want (CGI's, XML manipulation, ..).
A nice way to start your study is with this book: Apress Beginning Python From Novice to Professional.
After you see the examples and the simple structures, I suggest you to look the oficial site: http://www.python.org/ and the HOWTO examples: http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/index.html